# "Missing $ inserted" error in bibliography, no underscores

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, errors, compiling, biber

When I compile my thesis the following error pops up:

```
Underfull \hbox (badness 1264) in paragraph at lines 61--61
[]\T1/ppl/m/n/12 ^^U^^U^^U.^^P  Naples 2008, or, the Waste Land: Trash, Citizenship, and an Ethic of
[106]
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
            $
l.61
```

This happens in latexmk, or in pdflatex after I run biber. Other posters reporting the same error often nail it down to an underscore in the bibtex entry, but this is clearly not the case here:

```
@ARTICLE{iovino2009naples,
  author = {Iovino, Serenella},
  title = {Naples 2008, or, the Waste Land: Trash, Citizenship, and an Ethic of Narration},
  journaltitle = {Neohelicon},
  year = {2009},
  date = {2009-09},
  volume = {36},
  issue = {2},
  pages = {335--346},
  doi = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s11059-009-0004-6},
  url = {http://www.springerlink.com/index/10.1007/s11059-009-0004-6},
  file = {iovino2009naples.pdf:iovino2009naples.pdf:PDF},
  pdf = {iovino2009naples.pdf}
}
```

What is happening? What can I do?

[EDIT] Here's a MWE as requested:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, twoside, openright, draft]{book}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[style=mla,mladraft=true,backend=biber,bibencoding=utf8]{biblatex}
\bibliography{../bibtex/workscited.bib}
\begin{document}
\autocite{iovino2012wilderness}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Where the iovino2012wilderness entry is:

```
@INBOOK{iovino2012wilderness,
  author = {Iovino, Serenella},
  title = {The Wilderness of the Human Other: Italo Calvino's 'The Watcher' and a Reflection on the Future of Ecocriticism.},
  booktitle = {The Future of Ecocriticism},
  year = {2012},
  date = {2012},
  editor = {Serpil Oppermann, Ufuk \"{O}zda\breve{g}, Nevin \"{O}zkan and Scott
    Slovic},
  urldate = {2012-12-09},
  file = {iovino2012wilderness.pdf:iovino2012wilderness.pdf:PDF},
  pdf = {iovino2012wilderness.pdf},
  shorttitle = {The Wilderness of the Human Other}
}
```

This still produces errors:

```
Missing $ inserted \end
You can't use `\spacefactor' in math mode \end
Missing $ inserted \end
```

Comment: I've just tried your bibtex entry and it does not give me any error. I'm using pdflatex and bibtex. What bibliography style are you using?

Comment: there is something odd about that entry note `^^U^^U^^U.^^P  N` implies that you have control characters before the title, but the missing `$` error is unconnected with the input you show, it occurs on the following page, the under-full bib entry is on page 106 and the error is on the next page, on line 61 of your source file (or one of your source files)

Comment: Didac: I am using biblatex-mla.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle The `^^U^^U^^U.^^P` appear on the PDF as emdashes and are used to avoid repeating the author's name. Line 61 in my master document is blank. Line 60 is `\appendix`, but commenting that throws up the same error. Line 59 is `\printbibliography`. Commenting l.59 prevents the error from occurring but also does not print my bibliography. :(

Comment: Would you be able to narrow down the problem to a nice self-contained [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/)? The `.bib` entry posted above does not seem to be the culprit. Maybe it is the entry just before that in the bibliography (just a guess, might be off by quite some miles).

Comment: Hi @moewe. Thank you. I've edited my entry and provided a MWE.

Answer (score 7):

This one was due to the `\breve{g}`. Eliminating it lets me compile the document. I am using `\u{g}` instead.

Comment: Indeed `\breve{g}` is a math mode command, while `\u{g}` produces a breve in text mode.